Sequence Classification/Labelling in NLP
I am working on experimenting with sequence classification/labelling for nlp. I had some logical questions that require expert answers.
The questions are related to the dataset given in the link below.
Dataset: https://huggingface.co/datasets/surrey-nlp/PLOD-CW/viewer/default/train

Pre-processing: I am removing stopwords, punctuation and lemmatization. Is that the correct approach?

During pre-processing of my ‘tokens’ column, do I need to update the pos_tags and ner_tags columns accordingly as well or keep the rest of the columns the same?

Moving forward, do I need to vectorize and build model on the pre-processed data only? (New ‘tokens’, ‘pos_tags’, ‘ner_tags’ columns)


What I did:
I preprocessed only the ‘tokens’ column and kept other columns the same as in the original dataset.
What I expected:
I realized while visualizing the data that rest of the columns should also be updated
